# Finding the maximum repeating element(most popular) in an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Here is my code, please tell me whats wrong with it? I want to find the maximum repeating element of an array.

```
import java.util.*;
class solution {
public static void main (String args[]){

int i=0,j=0,k=0;
int count=-1,max=0,nmax=0,temp=0,temp2=0;
int a[]=new int[10];
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
int n=sc.nextInt();
while (i<n){
a[i]=sc.nextInt();
i++;
}

while(k<n){

  while (j<n){
   if(a[k]==a[j]){
     count++;
   }

    if(count>temp){
      temp=count;

    }
     j++;
  }


  if(temp>temp2){
    temp2=temp;
  max=a[k];
  }
  j=0;
  k++;
}

System.out.println(max);
}

}
```

I am getting the last element of an array as an output,Please let me know if there is any problem in the logic.Thanks in advance!

--------------------EDIT-------------------------

I didn't reassign the variables ,Here is the working code !

```
import java.util.*;
class Solution {
public static void main (String args[]){

int i=0,j=0,k=0;
int count=0,max=0,nmax=0,temp=0,temp2=0;
int a[]=new int[10];
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
int n=sc.nextInt();
while (i<n){
a[i]=sc.nextInt();
i++;
}

while(k<n){

  while (j<n){
   if(a[k]==a[j]){
     count++;
   }

    if(count>temp){
      temp=count-1;

    }
     j++;
  }

//System.out.println(temp);
  if(temp>temp2){
    temp2=temp;

  max=a[k];
  //System.out.println(max);
  }
  j=0;
  temp=0;
  k++;
  count=0;
}
System.out.println("The most repeating element is"+max);

}

}
```

Comment: Class name should be capital. solution -> Solution.

Comment: Thanks man,But it made no difference

Comment: The main problem is that the code is not indented, making it very hard, for you and for us, to reason about that code and visualize its structure.

Comment: I'll refactor  it then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
public static void main (String args[]){



    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    int count=0,temp=0,temp2=1;
    int a[]=new int[10];
    int max=a[0];
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    while (i<n){
    a[i]=sc.nextInt();
    i++;
    }

    while(k<n){
       temp = a[k];//put input elements into in temp
      while (j<n){
       if(temp==a[j]){ //check if any repeated element found 
         count++; //increment
       }

        if(count>temp2){ //if element present more than once
          max = temp;
          temp2 = count;
        }
         j++;
      }
      k++;
    }

    System.out.println(max);
}
```

**Input:**

```
5
2
3
4
3
1
```

**output:**

```
3
```

Comment: try to figure out where you done mistake for better learning.

Comment: yeah man ! I didn't reassign the value of variables back to '0' ,little mistake.Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @Ankurpandey if this is the right answer mark it right. happy coding keep learning. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is

```
max=a[k];
```

Instead of setting max to the element in the current position, you have to do your comparisons and only set max when the current element is greater than the current value of max.

Comment: sir could you be more specific please?